# OpenBSD, rcctl fails to start vmd

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, openbsd

I am on OpenBSD 6.8, under VirtualBox 6.1, with a virtualization capable Intel CPU. Following the virtualization guide on the OpenBSD website I ran `# rcctl enable vmd`, which seems to have completed successfully, then `# rcctl start vmd`, which returns `vmd(failed)`. The only reason for this I can think of is that OpenBSD is already running in a virtualized environment. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment, OpenBSD can not run as a VM host inside VirtualBox.

On OpenBSD installed on VirtualBox, you will notice

```
$ dmesg | grep vmm0
vmm0 at mainbus0: VMX
```

whereas on real hardware, you'll get something like

```
% dmesg | grep vmm0
vmm0 at mainbus0: VMX/EPT
```

The `EPT` is important, because without it, `vmmopen()` can't succeed.  When `vmmopen()` doesn't succeed, you'll get an error in your `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/daemon` saying

> `Apr 19 22:04:27 mymachine vmd[65518]: vmd: /dev/vmm: Operation not supported by device`

This is mentioned in a message to the `openbsd-misc` mailing list in 2016 ([here](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=147790859811572&w=2)), and it still seems to be the case.

If OpenBSD is unable to be used as a VM host in *any* type of virtualized setting or not, I cannot say.